# Fetch and store access_token and refresh_token for google drive android api

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using google drive android api for my application. How do I fetch the access and refresh tokens once I'm connected ? I am thinking to send these tokens to server and perform some operation. Not sure if it's possible. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you give access to your server by implementing the [GoogleApiClient.ServerAuthCodeCallbacks](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ServerAuthCodeCallbacks) interface. It allows you to request an auth code which you can send to your server to exchange for refresh and access tokens.

This is especially useful since you can specify different scopes for your server than for your client (Android) application. See these [Google Sign-In docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access) for an example implementation.

It is possible to get an access token from GoogleApiClient via something like GoogleAccountCredential or GoogleAuthUtil. There is no way of extracting a refresh token from a connected GoogleApiClient.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more question. In docs, .requestServerAuthCode(SERVER_CLIENT_ID, this) is used to send authcode to server. Is SERVER_CLIENT_ID is the ID of service account that you create under your android project in developer console or it's a different project in developer console. I am not able to fetch the tokens from authcode sent by Mobile to server. (Unauthorized client) Seems like some configuration issue :(

Comment: Create a "web application" Client ID for your server. That Client ID should be passed to the requestServerAuthCode method.